# Соответствует ли входная строка шаблону

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть шаблон вида XXX-XX-XXXXX-XX-X,где Х должен быть любой цифрой(не буквой!)
Необходимо проверить строку пользовательского ввода на строгое соответствие этому шаблону.Именно на строгое соответствие,а не на то,есть ли в этой строке вхождения шаблона
Как это можно реализовать с помощью регулярных выражений?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{5}-\d{2}-\d{1}$/g
```

Проверить можете [тут](https://regex101.com/r/SVPvSZ/1).